# Why are separators not appearing when using partials in a list?

Tags: dust.js

I have the following dust template fragment:

```
{#stdItems}
    {>"planItem" title=title description=description/}{@sep},{/sep}
{/stdItems}
```

My `planItem` template is thus:

```
{~lb}

{~rb}
```

My `stdItems` list has three items.

When I render this, I get:

```
{}{}{}
```

I expected to get:

```
{},{},{}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible explanation is that you haven't included the `dust-helpers` addon. `{@sep}` is part of the helpers; you can add them by running

```
npm install --save dustjs-helpers
```

If you turn on [Dust error logging](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/tips-and-tricks/), it's likely that you would see an error that the `sep` helper could not be found.

Comment: That was exactly it!